# How to set parameters inside a loop from controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello all I want to set parameters from controller.
I have nested params, and there are many of them. I want to iterate through params and set their values.

Here is my request model which has nested model filled_cartrdige:

```html
has_many :filled_cartridges, inverse_of: :request, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :filled_cartridges , allow_destroy: true
```

And here are my params when form is submitted:

```html
filled_cartridges_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cartridge_name"=>"HP new 2",
 "_destroy"=>"false",
 "client_id"=>"",
 "request_id"=>"",
 "cartridge_id"=>""}}
```

Notice empty params like client_id, I want to set their values inside controller before saving.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```html
# Iterate through nested params
params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes].each do |_,value|
# set param value,
  value[:client_id] = @client.id
```

Is it allowed to do like that?
Also do i need hidden fields for those params that are set from controller.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Michal, i edited my question a little bit.

Comment: Do you always change the same params, or do you need to check if they are nil every time?

Comment: @Michal, didn't get the question. I need to set parmeter value from controller method.

Comment: Can you not make it at the model level in a before_validation callback instead? This seems more like the railish way to do it.

Comment: @floum, can you suggest how to do it? I will try.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use map! method for this

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21

```
params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes].map! do |val|
  {
     client_id: @client.id,
     cartridge_name: val[:cartridge_name],
     #code omitted
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ActiveRecord Callback : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

```
class FilledCartridge
  belongs_to :client

  before_validation :set_client

   def set_client
     #set @client to the desired client
     client = @client
  end
end
```

Can't go further since I don't know how you got your @client in the controller in the first place.
You can also set the client_id (not the most preferred way).

This callback can be executed at any other level (before create if you want persistence of course).

With multiple attributes :

```
class FilledCartridge
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :request

  before_validation :set_attributes

   def set_attributes
     @client = Client.first #this should be changed
     @request = Request.first #this should be changed too
     client = @client
     request = @request
  end
end
```

Comment: But how do i set multiple params, i mean i need to iterate over them.

Comment: If the number of params is really high and it's not reasonable without an enumerable method, I would suggest that you send them from your form. In your example, how can I deduce which cartridge_id and which client_id my model will get?

Comment: no client_id,cartridge_id and request_id values has to be set to all params.

Comment: this callback will set client_id and request_id to any FilledCartridge when save, valid? and create are called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden fields in form and set the values. In that case, there is no need to iterate and set params at controller level.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'client_id', @client.id %>
```

But if don't want to add hidden fields and you simply want to track the client_id and do not want to create association of FilledCartridge, you can do assign it.

I think hidden field solution is better.

Comment: yep that would be a good solution, but I have one tricky part. What if i need to set request_id in hidden filed, and request is in only defined after create method call (because in new method request has id = nil, and it gets appropriate id after saving which occurs in create method)

Comment: Please if you can share your Request Controller. As in nested_form railcast following is the new method. So I think you don't need to set the request_id in controller.

def new
  survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = survey.questions.build
    4.times { question.answers.build }
  end
end

Railcast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1